# IE9 issue - Changing the placeholder attribute of an input tag with JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9, placeholder, html-input

When using the HTML5 placeholder attribute in an input tag, it displays fine in IE9 despite a lot of comments indicating otherwise.

For example:

```
<input id="email_input" placeholder="E-mail address" type="text" />
```

This indeed renders the placeholder text, even in IE9.

However, I'm now working with a project that uses JQuery Mobile to apply client-side language resources. This occurs within the **pagebeforecreate** event. With the case of placeholder text, the code might look something like this:

```
$(inputelem).attr("placeholder", resourceText);
```

The replacement works partially in IE9. If you inspect the input tag with the dev tools, the attribute has indeed been updated. But the text displayed in the browser remains the same. It's as if the browser rendering doesn't "know" that it should refresh the element after the placeholder attribute has been modified (the same code works for div:s, p:s etc).

Is there a trick to getting this to work in IE9, without having to resort to placeholder hacks (span overlays etc)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have recently updated to IE10. I tested it with `pagebeforecreate` and it works fine except for the _placeholder_ text styling. Are you facing the same problem when binding it to `pagebeforeshow`?

Comment: @Omar The result is the same: The placeholder attribute is updated but the value displayed is the old one. Could it be something that prevents the element to refresh its display view?

Comment: It should work with refreshing the textbox. Textbox doesn't accept `refresh`. but anyway, try these `.textinput('refresh')`, `textinput().trigger('refresh')`, `textinput().trigger('create')`. trial and error :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder IE9 - Javascript not executed in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103746/placeholder-ie9-javascript-not-executed-in-ie9)